# Will Stack Exchange sites start to include authorship markup?

Tags: feature-request, google, original-poster

See *[Webmaster Tools Help](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1229920)* for details on authorship markup.

Since folks that author 'answers' also tend to author longer form content, like blogs, tutorials and the like, linking their Stack Exchange 'personna' with their wider body of work seems like it would be beneficial to them.... and aren't they Stack Exchange users?

Comment: Summary? Reasons it will benefit SE and its users? Anything other than a "read this" link?

Comment: I guess folks are 'disinclined to acquiesce to your request'.  Got it.

Comment: +1 I can't comment on the viability of this specific standard, but there's nothing wrong with the basic idea.

Comment: @Pekka: Not sure how applicable it will be *here*, given the fun we're having with CW, CC-BY-SA and such.

Comment: @Piskvor: each question/answer has it's author or list of authors. Problems are more of technical nature.

Comment: @vartec: I know, but there's the rub: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19746/piskvors-semifinite-monkeys *may* be the same author as http://android.stackexchange.com/users/5194/piskvor , but without internal SE data (what accounts are linked) there's no one canonical author path; plus, what if I want to have *my* author link to point off-SE? (btw, "*its", not "it is")

Comment: @Piskvor: I believe that this solved by "the network profile", so in your case canonical author URI would be http://stackexchange.com/users/51040736-73fe-4de8-8e2b-d4de9fcb522e

Comment: @vartec: Cool, didn't know about *that*. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1):

Reading your link, it seems to be only useful to blogs, news articles, journals, etc. It is to increase search history and linking to authors so you can find your favorite author's articles more easily. That's what I get from it. I don't think it will be useful for SE.

Comment: After reading through some of the really high quality answers that get posted on Stackoverflow, I have noticed that they tend to be  'blog entry-ish'.

Comment: @vkraemer: I don't know if I agree with that, but I think for the context of SE sites, your suggestion does not jive with the nature of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Question and answers in SE are contained in `<div>`'s, meanwhile [HTML5 specification states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-author):

> The `author` keyword may be used with
>   `link`, `a`, and `area` elements.

Comment: I would imagine, were this to be implemented, that the link in the question asker/answerer (as appropriate)'s flair to the user page would have the author keyword on it.